# Tagging metrics in Application Insights for NodeJS

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-application-insights

I am currently adding Application Insights into my NodeJS application, I have the package installed and successfully transmitting data, however I would like to add additional tags to each data point as it is sent.

Looking at the docs, it seems a Telemetry Processor is the place to do this, but using the code below I cannot see the tags in the Azure Portal.

```
var TraceProcessor = function (envelope) {
    envelope.tags['TestTag'] = 'Test Tag';
    return true;
};
module.exports = TraceProcessor;
```

I can see the code being executed and the tag being added, but cannot see this tag to filter by it in the Azure Portal.

Am I adding the tags correctly and if so where can I filter the data by these in the portal?

Comment: According the definition `tag` property of `envelope` in source code at https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-node.js/blob/master/Library/Client.ts#L215, it seems that is validated in https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-node.js/blob/master/Library/Context.ts#L49 of `context` class. Could you please clarify your requirement?

Comment: Thanks for the response. What I'd like to do is be able to add additional information to each metric as it is sent out and then filter by this piece of information when analyzing the data. The tag name would be the same for each data point but the value could be different.


From looking at the C# version of insights I thought I might be able to do this using Tags -
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/01/07/application-insights-support-for-multiple-environments-stamps-and-app-versions/


Is there a similar mechanism for NodeJS?

Comment: I've struggled a bit with this today, and it seems tags are bound to objects that Azure already know about (e.g. the application) and data is the one we should use for extra information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured this out and it eventually turned out to be a combination of both my original approach and the one suggested by John.

```
var TraceProcessor = function (envelope) {
    envelope.data.baseData.properties['TraceID'] = 'trace1';
    return true;
};
module.exports = TraceProcessor;
```

Custom properties were indeed what I needed, but the telemetry processor I already had was what was needed to be able to do this with the automatic telemetry for every request.

Answer (score 0):

i think what you're looking for is "custom properties" (the sample above uses a custom property *named* "Tag").  all of the methods in the SDKs generally allow you to pass a dictionary of string key:value pairs, and those properties travel with all those events.  for all the non metric calls, like TrackEvent, you can actually pass a dictionary of custom properties *and* a dictionary (string:double) of custom metrics as well).

c# sdk in `TelemetryClient`:

```
public void TrackMetric(string name, double value, IDictionary<string, string> properties = null)
```

or using metrics AND properties in a trackevent call:

```
public void TrackEvent(string name, IDictionary<string, string> properties = null, IDictionary<string, double> metrics = null)
```

JavaScript SDK (well, from the ts interfaces anyway), from `AppInsights.prototype`

```
trackMetric(name: string, average: number, sampleCount?: number, min?: number, max?: number, properties?: { [name: string]: string; });
```

any properties you send there *should* show up as filtering options in metrics explorer or in the analytics query tool.

Comment: Thanks for the response - Maybe I am misunderstanding, wouldn't using TrackMetric and TrackEvent force me to implement the tracking of events manually rather than use the automatic telemetry?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out two things today:

"tags" are useful, but should (only?) be used for general properties that Azure cares about, i.e.:

```
envelope.tags['ai.cloud.role'] = 'Name of your application (or part of application) as you want it to show up in Application Insights Map or elsewhere.';
```

Freeform data however should go under envelope data:

```
envelope.data.environment = process.env.REACT_APP_APPLICATION_INSIGHTS_ENVIRONMENT;
```

This can be done on top level like this for properties that doesn't change after the app has started:

```
[...]
appInsights.loadAppInsights();

appInsights.addTelemetryInitializer((env: ITelemetryItem) => {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
  env.tags = env.tags || [];

  // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
  env.tags['ai.cloud.role'] = 'foo-webclient';

  // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
  env.data = env.data || [];

  // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
  env.data.environment = process.env.REACT_APP_APPLICATION_INSIGHTS_ENVIRONMENT;
});
[...]
```

Edit: looking into the browser network log I see this data gets embedded into data.baseData.properties.